# Can we say " I'm craving to see you all."?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, american-english, questions

I'm craving to see you all. Is this a correct usage?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. Would you please provide some references as to why it might or might not be correct? Offhand, I would say it is grammatical but not felicitous. I could *crave* ice cream or cigarettes, but perhaps better: *I'm longing to see you.*

Comment: Did you look for the meaning of 'crave' in a dictionary?

Comment: No. It is not idiomatic to say this. If you did, people might think that you have some unhealthy and unnatural desires.

Comment: @FelimiusRex why is it necessary to take craving as in here literally? In a non formal setting won't it convey a strong longing as if a person is craving?

Comment: @Kashmiri It is not necessary. It's just the way the the great majority of people would understand it. So don't use it unless you want to display your ignorance of English idiom.

Comment: I saw somebody used this somewhere. It also made me confused. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

It is technically correct but strikes me as extremely odd -- perhaps jocular.

I would usually expect someone to say, "I'm looking forward to seeing you all again," or "I want to see you all again."  or for emphasis, perhaps, "I long to see you all again."

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard "craving" used with an infinitive. "Longing" is usual.

Answer (score 0):

In general, craving is used for food or drink.

It is mostly in the present simple, though continuous is possible:

**I really crave a glass of ice water.**
**I crave an ice cream right now.**
** I'm craving a swim in the ocean. It is so hot.**

**The verb crave takes a *direct object***, so, one could say:

I'm craving or I crave **seeing** you all. [seeing is a noun]

It is not idiomatic to say: crave to [verb]

Common with the verb crave:

- attention
- recognition
- many abstract nouns.
- things, especially food